# How did the angel in "בבואו מאדום" Zemer make three mistakes?

Tags: shabbat, messiah, malach-angel, meal-seudah, shabbat-songs

I have always been puzzled by "בבואו מאדום" Zemer that many sing at Seuda Shlishis (actually found in the Bentcher as part of "Boruch Hashem Yom Yom"):

> בְּבוֹאוֹ מֵאֱדוֹם חֲמוּץ בְּגָדִים, זֶבַח לוֹ בְּבָצְרָה וְטֶבַח לוֹ בּבוֹגְדִים, וְיֵז נִצְחָם מַלְבוּשָׁיו לְהַאְדִּים, בְּכֹחוֹ הַגּדוֹל יִבְצֹר רוּחַ נְגִידִים, הָגָה בְּרוּחוֹ הַקָּשָׁה בְּיוֹם קָדִים. רְאוֹתוֹ כִּי כֵן אֲדֹמִי הָעוֹצֵר, **יַחְשָׁב לוֹ בָּצְרָה תִקְלֹט כְּבֶצֶר, וּמַלְאָךְ כְּאָדָם בְּתוֹכָהּ יִנָּצֵר, וּמֵזִיד כַּשּׁוֹגֵג בְּמִקְלָט יֵעָצֵר**, אֶהֱבוּ אֶת 
>   ה׳ כָּל חֲסִידָיו אֱמוּנִים נוֹצֵר

The angel fleeing from before Hashem when Moshiach comes makes three glaring mistakes:

- He thought that Botzrah (not an Ir Miklat) sheltered like Betzer (a certified Ir Miklat)
- He thought that a Malach could be considered as a person and be
  sheltered in an Ir Miklat
- He thought that a Meizid (purposeful killer) could be
  sheltered there like a Shogeig (accidental killer)

What does it mean that an angel makes those mistakes? I think that this Zemer is just shouting for a deeper explanation. Does anyone have something to share?

Comment: For reference, that part of the zemer is clearly based on Reish Lakish’s teaching in Makkos 12a. Everyone that I’ve seen commenting there seems to focus on the importance of those mistakes, rather than how they’re made in the first place. Keep in mind that this is the same Malach we pull the same trick on *every single year* when we don’t blow the Shofar on Erev Rosh Hashanah. I wonder if the point is that the Yetzer Hara, while crafty, isn’t very bright, and hence yet another Gemara’s teaching that a person can only sin when possessed by a spirit of insanity.

Comment: @DonielF, I don't think the point is the Yetzer Harah isn't very bright. A malach cannot be compared on the level of man. We do find in other areas that malachim seem to make mistakes, which in general, I believe, requires some explanation.

Comment: @Doodle, honestly the malach could've made any one of those 3 mistakes and it would've been enough. Just interesting to point out.

Comment: @Rafael I meant that somewhat facetiously. It is noteworthy that in the various other instances where malachim err - Uzzah and Uzziah sinning in the Dor HaMabul, Gavriel and Michael claiming that they were destroying Sedom, etc. - they’re always in human form. I believe the Satan is the only Malach where we find that he sins even when playing the role of Malach.

Comment: @DonielF I would be really interested if you could explain what you mean by "the importance" of the mistakes. Perhaps that's a part of the answer. What do you mean that the Y"H sins in the role of malach?

Comment: @Rafael Quite right, it just excacipates the issue.

Comment: not an answer, because it's original, but these are the mistakes the evil inclination makes *us* make: blurring the difference between 'by mistake' and 'on  purpose', making things 'basically the same so it's alright'  and 'if it's good for him it's good for me'

Comment: @Orangesandlemons I really, really like that thought.

Comment: I have expanded the question a little...

Comment: @Rafael See the Ben Yehoyada to the Gemara I cited. It’s not so clear that just one would have been enough - he holds that all three are necessary.

Comment: @Doodle By “importance” I mean, for instance, the comment of the Ben Yehoyada I cited to Refael. By “role of Malach” I mean that the malachim I cited earlier were all disguised as humans when they sinned; Samael isn’t wearing any sort of disguise here. My Rebbe (Rabbi Yochanan Zweig Shlit”a) explains the other Midrashim as that when a Malach takes on human form, he accepts the Yetzer Hara as well, giving them the potential to sin. That doesn’t work here since A) he’s not in human form and B) he *is* the Yetzer Hara. IYH I will ask him next time I see him.

Comment: The term 'malach' (מלאך) can also mean simply an agent (of G-d), a shaliach, who doesn't have any choice in their mission. Your text is saying "an angel (who is) like a man. Man has choice, but the angel doesn't. Armilus HaRasha (who was a Jew) is referred to in some sources as "the Satan" or "that Satan" (also as the anti-Moshiach). Your quote says that the one fleeing thought Basra would provide refuge, 'like' Betzer. Not that it was Betzer. This seems to be referring to the formation of the Gulf Cooperation Council by Shimon Peres as a consequence of the Oslo Accords.

Comment: @Yaacov Deane thanks for the attention to detail, I have altered the Betzer / Botzrah mistake. I'm not sure I understand the rest of your comments.

Comment: @DonielF will IY"H look it up.

Comment: @AlBerko thank you for your edits. As a new user please do excuse my horrifying chutzpah, just feeling my way around... My old title was way more intriguing. Will anyone even visit this page now?

Comment: @Doodle As is pointed out in the midrashim which discuss the birth of Armilus HaRasha, he is not a normal human being. It indicates that his creation is rooted in the same aspect of Gevurah that caused the 'Tzimtzum HaRishon' at the very beginning of creation. This means the total concealment of G-d's presence. Armilus HaRasha did not have free choice, like other Jews. He is like an angel with the appearance of a Jew. A similar concept (the elimination of free choice) is discussed by Rambam in Hilchot Teshuva in connection with Pharaoh.

Comment: And just to put it in context, Armilus HaRasha was supposed to intentionally murder Moshiach ben Yosef (to be a Meizid) via one of his followers.